# Statistic Collection by "signal, emit and statistic" feature Without modifying omnet++ model (TicToc tutorial 5.3 )

Tags: networking, collections, statistics, modeling, omnet++

Actually, I have modelled a virus network and I want to collect the end result that how many people have been dead and recovered at the end of the simulation. I have gone through the tictoc tutorial 5.3 but still don't understand how to implement similar thing on my model. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

At the code points where the state of the agent changes `emit()` `died` or `recovered` signals (and the required `@signal()` lines in the module's NED file. When that is implemented in your code, you can add `@statistics` at the network level NED and you can configure to get the `sum()` of the emitted signals, which would give you the number of `died` and `recovery` signals over the whole simulation.

Obviously, you can do much more complicated calculations also on the fly using various filters (moving average etc.) or via post processing by analyzing the actual result files.

But generally, the tutorial step in 5.3 clearly describes, how to add statistics, so it's not clear what is your **actual** question? Note that stating that you do NOT understand something is not considered a question os SO.